# httpCompression not work inside web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-7.5, iis-8, applicationhost

Is their anyway to make httpCompression work from inside web.config ?

i try to add this in my web.config but it's does nothing :

```
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />    
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Comment: It is by design. Please upgrade to IIS 10.

Comment: in IIS 10 we can change it in the web.config ?

Comment: yes, IIS 10 supports that fully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overriding compression related settings in `web.config` is considered a new addition in IIS 10,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2017/09/05/iis-dynamic-compression-and-new-dynamic-compression-features-in-iis-10/

So to answer your question, you have to upgrade to IIS 10.

Comment: I'm using IIS 10 and it still doesn't work, with `<section name="httpCompression" allowDefinition="Everywhere" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`

Comment: I'm trying to remove brotli like this: `<clear />
            <scheme name="gzip" dll="%ProgramFiles%\IIS\IIS Compression\iiszlib.dll" doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" staticCompressionLevel="10" dynamicCompressionLevel="10" />` but it still usesbrotli even after `net stop was /y && net start w3svc`

Comment: @MaximMazurok that's not surprising, as the whole discussion (either here or in the Microsoft employee blog post) only covers basic elements like `dynamicTypes`. It is possible that overriding `scheme` in `web.config` is ignored by IIS.

Comment: That makes sense... Could you please take a look at my question regarding this matter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266508/how-to-disable-brotli-httpcompression-in-iis-10-on-the-site-web-config-level

Comment: @MaximMazurok yes, I saw that but I have nothing more to comment. You have to reach out to Microsoft.